# Find the time interval, when there was the greatest number of visitors

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to find the time interval in which there was a maximum number of visitors. I take the visit time of each visitor from the file.
File content example:

```
09:37,09:46
10:00,10:30
10:10,10:40
10:20,10:50
```

Expected output based on the file data above:

```
09:37 - 09:46;1
10:20 - 10:30;3
10:20 - 10:40;2
10:20 - 10:50;1
```

Actual result:

```
09:37 - 09:46;1
10:20 - 10:30;4
10:20 - 10:30;4
10:20 - 10:30;4
```

My code:

```
public class Algo {
    public void Algo(String pathname) {
        try {
            File myObj = new File(pathname);
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>();

            LocalTime entranceTime;
            LocalTime leavingTime;

            LocalTime currEntrance;
            LocalTime currLeaving;
            int count;


            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                times.add(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
            System.out.println(times);

            for (int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
                entranceTime = LocalTime.parse(times.get(i).split(",")[0]);
                leavingTime = LocalTime.parse(times.get(i).split(",")[1]);
                count = 1;

                for (int j = 1; j < times.size(); j++) {
                    currEntrance = LocalTime.parse(times.get(j).split(",")[0]);
                    currLeaving = LocalTime.parse(times.get(j).split(",")[1]);

                    if (!entranceTime.isAfter(currLeaving) && !currEntrance.isAfter(leavingTime)) {
                        count++;
                        if (currEntrance.compareTo(entranceTime) >= 0) {
                            entranceTime = currEntrance;
                        }
                        if (currLeaving.compareTo(leavingTime) <= 0) {
                            leavingTime = currLeaving;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(entranceTime + " - " + leavingTime + ";" + count);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, it is absolutely unclear how the expected output is calculated from the given input.

Comment: the file contains the visitor's entry and exit times, I have to compare each time with the next one, whether they intersect with each other.  If they intersect, then I must display this time and calculate how many visitors were also at that time

Comment: No need to ping me. If I have information to add, I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy. for obtain the output you wat just do j=i+1 not j=1 because with this you cont the same again in each iteration, to avoid that just do this

```
 for (int j = i+1; j < times.size(); j++)
```

then you have the espected output.